# Two frame animations in a sequence

Tags: android, animation, frame, sequence

I have an application that has a constant frame animation on its main page. I use the `setBackgroundResource` to show the animation.

From time to time I need to show other frame animation (`secondary`) and then get back to the primary animation. The problem I have is that if I call `Animate`(`secondary`) and then `Animate`(`primary`), the primary overlaps the secondary as if it is being processed immediately without waiting for the secondary animation to complete. How can I wait for the secondary animation to complete and only then to get back to the primary animation.

Thanks,
  Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can set an animation listener to startup the first animation upon completion of the second.

```
secondAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            firstAnimation.startNow()
        }
    });
```